# ASP.NET Core でのセッションの利用

Tags: asp.net, cookie, session, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core でのセッションとアプリの状態
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2

サンプルソース
https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/app-state/samples/2.x/SessionSample

上記のチュートリアルとサンプルソースを参考にしていますが、セッションが有効になりません。
・リクエストをまたいでセッションの値が保持されていない
・Cookie にセッションIDが設定されていない
サンプルソースをそのまま実行しても同様です。
何か設定等が足りないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

理由はよくわかりませんが、
以下の行をコメントアウトすることでセッションを使用できるようになりました。

Startup.cs

```
options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
```

Comment: 検索するとこれ [ASP.NET Core での EU 一般データ保護規則 (GDPR) のサポート](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/security/gdpr?view=aspnetcore-2.2) が出てきます。調査・実験や内部使用なら削除しても大丈夫でしょうが、不特定多数に公開する何かで使用するなら、対処が必要でしょうね。